# Pandas DataFrame extract columns where all

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following Dataframe I am trying to get a dataframe that excludes rows where all the values are 1

```
columns  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i
index
foo      1  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  1
bar      1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
bas      0  1  1  1  1  0  1  1  1
qux      0  1  0  1  1  0  0  0  0
```

So from the above we should end up with a data frame that doesn't contain the bar row such as this.

```
columns  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i
index
foo      1  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  1
bas      0  1  1  1  1  0  1  1  1
qux      0  1  0  1  1  0  0  0  0
```

I was wondering if there was something like df.dropna but for a value.

df.drop('Where row contains all 1s', axis=0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use `==` and `~all()`:

```
>>> df
     a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i
foo  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  1
bar  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
bas  0  1  1  1  1  0  1  1  1
qux  0  1  0  1  1  0  0  0  0
>>> (df == 1).all(axis=1)
foo    False
bar     True
bas    False
qux    False
dtype: bool
>>> df[~(df == 1).all(axis=1)]
     a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i
foo  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  1
bas  0  1  1  1  1  0  1  1  1
qux  0  1  0  1  1  0  0  0  0
```

Note that here we could also simply write `df[~df.all(axis=1)]`, because you're only working with 0s and 1s.